# ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED (Nuxt 3 with Node.js 17.4)

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, package.json, nuxtjs3

I'm creating a website with [Nuxt 3](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/) and [Express 4](https://expressjs.com/) and trying to deploy it via *git* on a Gandi *Simple Hosting* instance. While it works well locally (Node.js 16.13.0), when deployed (Node.js 17.4) I have this error caused by the *unenv* package import:

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './runtime/polyfill/fetch.node' is not defined by "exports" in /srv/data/web/vhosts/default/client/.output/server/node_modules/unenv/package.json imported from /srv/data/web/vhosts/default/client/.output/server/index.mjs
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:290:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:496:3)
    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:618:14)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:670:18)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:784:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:229:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

I'm not the only one who have this error, as it can be seen in this open issue, concerning deployment on Firebase: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/2151.

The *unnev* package.json distributed with the Nuxt 3 nitro server is:

```
{
  "name": "unenv",
  "version": "0.4.3",
  "description": "",
  "repository": "unjs/unenv",
  "license": "MIT",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "require": "./dist/index.cjs",
      "import": "./dist/index.mjs"
    },
    "./runtime/*": {
      "require": "./runtime/*.cjs",
      "import": "./runtime/*.mjs"
    }
  },
  "main": "./dist/index.cjs",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "runtime"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "unbuild",
    "lint": "eslint --ext ts .",
    "prepack": "unbuild",
    "release": "standard-version && npm publish && git push --follow-tags"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "buffer": "^6.0.2",
    "defu": "^5.0.0",
    "events": "^3.2.0",
    "inherits": "^2.0.4",
    "mime": "^2.4.6",
    "node-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "upath": "^2.0.1",
    "util": "^0.12.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "latest",
    "@types/node": "latest",
    "@types/node-fetch": "latest",
    "consola": "latest",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "standard-version": "latest",
    "typescript": "latest",
    "unbuild": "latest"
  }
}
```

[This non-Nuxt issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/16623) (Storybook.js) suggests that **before Node 17** only a warning was thrown.

Even if I can consider downgrading my Node.js version, I would like to know if **this error can be fixed on Node.js 17** and, if not, **how the `"exports"` entry could be refactored** to make it work.

Comment: Can you try setting `"./*": "./*"` in `"exports"`?

Comment: Thank you @gabrielmaldi. I'll try this on the unenv package.json. I'd like not to have to edit the original package.json file, but you answer my second question. I'm not used to this `exports` entry. I'll give it a try. Thanks again.